# Button для другого Activity из Fragment

Tags: java, android

Всем привет. Я столкнулся с одной проблемой, из-за которой не получается сделать 2 кнопки для перехода в два разных активити с одного из моих фрагментов. Я буду очень благодарен, если вы мне поможете разобраться с этим.

```
/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 * Use the {@link SearchFragment#newInstance} factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 */
public class SearchFragment extends Fragment {


    private Button menButton, womanButton;

    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    public SearchFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment SearchFragment.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static SearchFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        SearchFragment fragment = new SearchFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_search, container, false);

    }
}
```

Comment: В приведённом коде нет кнопок, нет попыток перехода в к-л актвиити. Также не указано какая  именно проблема у вас возникает. Без всего этого - сложно сказать что не так. Вообще всё описанное в одну строку делается. Вот пример на Kotlin: `btn.setOnClickListener { context.startActivity(context, MainActivity::class.java) }`

Comment: Я решил свою проблему. Спасибо за ваш отклик